# SonarQube with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have integrated SonarQube with Eclipse with the help of a plugin. Now within Eclipse, I am able to test the server connection to Sonar successfully. But when I try to associate a java -maven project with sonar, I don't see any results. I am not clear as to how I go about resolving this issue.Currently the pom.xml of the project does not have the sonar plugin.Do I have to manually install the sonar server outside of eclipse?I think not as with the help of the plugin inside eclipse I am able to test the connection to the server.Please help in associating my project to SonarQube and run the scanner.

Answer (score 0):

In your project directory, there would be a `sonar-project.properties` file. You'll have to add this to your project directory, if it doesn't exist.

`sonar-project.properties` looks like this

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=packagename
sonar.projectName=projectname
sonar.projectVersion=projectversion

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=src
```

Make sure you also have `sonar-runner` installed.

Comment: Thanks @Tejas.Actually I don't have a sonar-project.properties file in this java project of mine.Is this something that I should add to the project?

Comment: I did try but it failed as the pom.xml of the application did not have a reference to the sonar plugin I think.

Comment: I have updated the answer with sample `sonar-project.properties`. Install sonar-runner and run it from your project directory.

Comment: Thanks @tejas.Do we have to provide database related information-url,username and password in settings.xml when connecting to sonar?

Comment: Also,I need to install SonarQube first correct?As of now I connect to the sonar server using the eclipse plugin through eclipse.